# Swift add Custom View to screen with UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview

Tags: ios, swift, view

hope this is an easy one...

I am in a empty new project.

I have added a custom view called MyCustomView:

```
import UIKit

public class MyCustomView: UIView{

private var littleView: UIView!

open class func show() -> UIView{

    let bigView = MyCustomView()

    bigView.configureView()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(bigView)

    return bigView
}

private func configureView(){

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        width: screenSize.width,
                        height: screenSize.height)

    littleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
    littleView.backgroundColor = .black
    addSubview(littleView)
}
}
```

In the ViewController doing this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    let test = MyFirstView.show()
 }
```

I hoped this will present the view, but I still have to use `self.view.addSubview(test)` to see it....

I thought with `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(bigView)` and adding a subView to it, it should present the View.

What am I missing?

Comment: Tried in viewDidAppear ??

Comment: ...that did it :-/
makes sense xD

Comment: ok , added as answer for future references

Comment: was about to delete for being a silly question...but I guess I can leave it for others as blind as myself. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the subview in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
 let test = MyFirstView.show()
}
```